# Parse configuration remote configuration file

Tags: bash, ssh, pipe, config

I want to read in a remote configuration file in a bash script; locally the following works fine:

```
while IFS="=" read -r name value; do
    declare "$name=$value"
done < "$cfg"
```

I tried to do the same using `ssh` and `cat`:

```
ssh "$hostname" "cat $remote_cfg" |
while IFS="=" read -r name value; do
    declare "$name=$value"
    echo $name $value
done
```

But my variables are only declared in scope of the while loop, how can I bring them to the outer scope?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured things out (source: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Process substitution works:

```
while IFS="=" read -r name value; do
    declare "$name=$value"
done < <(ssh "$hostname" "cat ~/.cuttleline.cfg")
```